Docker - Gitlab Runner Register 403 error with personal token
I am trying to register instance of gitlab runner with personal token, however I getting 403 error.
If I use token from web interface then everything is fine.
Steps for reproduce,
docker exec -it $gitlab_instance_hash gitlab-rails runner "token = User.find_by_username('root').personal_access_tokens.create(scopes: ['create_runner'], name: 'Automation token', expires_at: 365.days.from_now); token.set_token('1111111111111111'); token.save;"
docker exec -it $gitlab_runner_hash gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url "http://url.site" --token "1111111111111111" --executor "shell" --description "shell-runner"

Error message,
Runtime platform                                    arch=amd64 os=linux pid=23 revision=66a723c3 version=17.5.0
Running in system-mode.

Token specified trying to verify runner...
WARNING: If you want to register use the '-r' instead of '-t'.
ERROR: Verifying runner... is removed               runner=11111111 status=POST http://url.site/api/v4/runners/verify: 403 Forbidden
PANIC: Failed to verify the runner. You may be having network problems.


GitLab - v17.5.0
GitLab Runner - v17.5.0

I did not find any messages which will help with solving the issue.
what am I doing wrong?

Probably your token has expired, according to the documentation a 403 refers to invalid credentials https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/runners.html#verify-authentication-for-a-registered-runner

problem could be with the registration token?
Use the registration token obtained from the GitLab UI instead of the personal access token.
Update your registration command as follows:
docker exec -it $gitlab_runner_hash gitlab-runner register --non-interactive --url "http://url.site" --registration-token YOUR-REGISTRATION-TOKEN --executor "shell" --description "shell-runner"
